# How to run a scheduled task using electron.net

Tags: c#, electron.net

I need a task to run every 60 seconds to go out and fetch data from a web api. Once the data comes back it will process the data which should not freeze the gui when processing. Is there a way to do this using electron.net?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in order to do that you must make this task in another thread, one way to do that is to use Microsoft BackgroundWorker (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: actually the solution needs to be cross platform

Comment: BackgroundWorker exists for almost all platforms, are you looking for some specific platform that i can help you with? Take a look at the link below, it describes all platforms that support BackgroundWorker: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Another potential here would be to use a Task, then provide a CancellationToken to it so that during program shut-down, you can dispose of the Task gracefully.